# What is the WMI class to manage BitLockerToGo

Tags: wmi, bitlocker

I am working on a script that will be used to audit some machines. I can check whether or not volumes are encrypted using the Win32_EncryptableVolume class in root\cimv2\Security\EncryptableVolume. What class can I can query for info on BitLockerToGo ? (Encrypting Removable Drives)

How can you check what BitlockerToGo settings are enforced on a computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Registry keys that are related to BitlockerToGo. They determine whether or not a user can write to an unencrypted removable disk or not.

Deny write access to removable drives (USB, IEEE 1394, SD card, etc.) not protected by BitLocker:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVDenyWriteAccess
REG_DWORD 0x1
```

Deny write access to fixed drives (internal non-OS HDDs, external eSATA drives) not protected by BitLocker:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\FDVDenyWriteAccess
REG_DWORD 0x1
```

I'd still be interested to hear if this is in WMI as well, but pulling from the registry is just as easy for me.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT you use the same WMI interfaces for removable volumes that you do for fixed disks: GetEncryptionMethod will tell you if the volume is encrypted and, if so, with what algorithm/key length.